# Flash builder Mobile AS3 project: Center a DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, mobile, center

**EDIT:** See also next question on Stackoverflow:
[Flash builder Mobile AS3 project: Screen DPI, Application DPI, image DPI, center image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610807/flash-builder-mobile-as3-project-screen-dpi-application-dpi-image-dpi-center)

It has something to do with DPI settings.......

---

I want to center a DisplayObject to the center of the screen. This is an image dynamically created from a resource. I use the the following code to center the object after it is created:

```
public function showProgress(bValue : Boolean = true):void
{
  this.imgProgress.visible = bValue;
  if( bValue )
  {
    this.imgProgress.x = (this.stage.stageWidth - this.imgProgress.width) * 0.5;
  }
}
```

Looks quite simple to me but the object is still not in the center. For example:

```
this.stage.stageWidth == 500;
this.imgProgress.width == 480;
Result is: 10px; (this.imgProgress.x) /* 10px is correct */
```

I tried several things, also with localToGlobal and GlobalToLocal but getting unpredictable results, still not centered.

I think it has something to do with the screen dpi or something? But the Capabilities.screenDPI returns strange results. For example, running as iPhone 3GS it returns 163dpi.

How do i calculate the correct center position?

**EDIT:
Some extra info:**

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
// setup stage
this.stage.color = 0;
this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

imgProgress is a child of this.stage

Comment: `(stage.stageWidth - displayObject.width) / 2` is correct, so perhaps there is something going on with the registration point of the image or there is some transparent space in the image or even you've just scaled up/down the SWF with the `scaleMode` not set to `TOP_LEFT`.

Comment: Agreed this code is only correct if the displayObject is a child of the stage, if it is the child of another DisplayObjectContainer that is not at 0,0 in the stage then the centering will be off.

Comment: Wow, that's fast, thanks. The DisplayObject is added to that stage and this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT and this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE. Dividing by 2 is the same as multiply by 0.5. Multiply is safer according to avoid dividing by zero for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to with the aspect ratio (when calculated you are able to center it correcly)

See also:
[Set ApplicationDPI in AS3 Mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644314/set-applicationdpi-in-as3-mobile-application)